# Rails "Create or Update" model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have the following code:

```
FluidsurveysSurvey.all do |survey|
  ResponseSummary.where(:survey_id => survey.id).first_or_create do |response_summary|
    response_summary.count = count
  end
end
```

I believe that this will either find the `ResponseSummary` with the given `survey.id`, or create it and add a `count`. The issue is that I want to update the `count` no matter what. So, if the `ResponseSummary` with that survey_id is found, update the `count`. Otherwise, create the `ResponseSummary` and update the `count`. I am using Rails 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want servey id in newly created account:

```
FluidsurveysSurvey.all do |survey|
  response = ResponseSummary.find_or_create_by_servey_id(survey.id)
response.update_column(:count, count)
end
```

If you don't want servey_id in newly created account:

```
FluidsurveysSurvey.all do |survey|
  response = ResponseSummary.find_by_servey_id(survey.id)||ResponseSummary.create
response.update_column(:count, count)
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll go with something similar to the first method here, it just seemed like there should be a "find_or_update_by" method in rails. Anyways, thanks for the tips!